# Loading model objects in Laravel when passing primarykey in new()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I'm beginning to play around with Eloquent models. I've got the following model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Character
 * @package App
 *
 * @property string $name
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $score
 */
class Character extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'characters';

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible when I do the following:

> $character = new Character( 1 ); // 1 is the primary key

I'd like it to go ahead and load the model with the info in the database. If it doesn't exist, I'd like to set `1` as `$character->id`. Is this possible? Or does Eloquent already do this and I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can do it by this:

```
public function __construct($primaryKey)
{
  parent::__construct($attributes);
  $character = self::find($primaryKey);

  if(is_null($character)){
    $character = self::find(1);
  }
  return $character;
}
```

But, ideally you should not do this because Laravel is not designed this way. You better do the same thing outside of the model. Besides, there is another problem in this code, we are hard coding the `$primaryKey = 1` if the object is not found. Such hard coded value can be risky sometimes.

Comment: He can use `self::first()` if he wants first model when for input primary key, there is no record.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Eloquent is not designed to work this way. Overriding the constructor like this is bound to cause plenty of issues down the road.

Consider adding a static method for your use-case - much like Imran's solution above. That way you can enjoy the odd behaviour that you're after without risking breaking anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution you can get is using findOrNew() function https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_findOrNew.

You can use it as

```
$character = Character::findOrNew(1);
```

This will query the characters table for id 1 and will return an instance of the Character model, if the id is not found in the database a new instance of Character model will be instantiated and returned. However there is no option for setting the id of the model.